# Update table with subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I hava the following table in database (Access - Microsoft SQL Server):

```
| Product Id |  Month    | Sales |
----------------------------------
| 1144       |  1        | 100   |
| 20131120   |  1        | 200   |
| 1144       |  2        | 333   |
| 1144       |  3        | 333   |
| 1144       |  4        | 333   |
| 1144       |  5        | 333   |
| 20131120   |  2        | 200   |
```

And I would like to add to the table new column which will show in how many months each products has been sold till particular month. I need to keep this information in database, in this table.

After updating table I would like to get the table:

```
| Product Id |  Month    | Sales | Counter |
-------------------------------------------|
| 1144       |  1        | 100   |   0     |
| 20131120   |  1        | 200   |   0     |
| 1144       |  2        | 333   |   1     |
| 1144       |  3        | 333   |   2     |
| 1144       |  4        | 333   |   3     |
| 1144       |  5        | 333   |   4     |
| 20131120   |  2        | 200   |   1     |
```

For example, for product=1144 and month=3, counter=2 because this item has appeared twice till 3 month.

I would like to update column Counter with one query (update set = (select ... )). Could you help me to construct the query ?

Comment: Depending on the type of Database you are running you can create an on update trigger on the table that will update the new column.

Comment: Um, which RDBMS please. Answer below for SqlServer OFC. Also, surely the counters for (1144, 1) and (20131120, 1) as there are non-zero sales that month?

Comment: @StuartLC: it's mentioned in the question "database (access)" - so I guess it's MS Access.

Comment: It is Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should retrive the correct data:

```
SELECT    m1.product_id, m1.month, m1.sales, COUNT(m2.month) - 1 AS counter
  FROM    mysales AS m1 INNER JOIN
          mysales AS m2 ON m1.product_id = m2.product_id AND m1.month >= m2.month
 GROUP BY m1.product_id, m1.month, m1.sales
```

so the statment to update the table once you added the counter column is:

```
UPDATE    mysales
   SET    counter = x.counter
  FROM    (SELECT    m1.product_id, m1.month, COUNT(m2.month) - 1 AS counter
             FROM    mysales AS m1 INNER JOIN
                     mysales AS m2 ON m1.product_id = m2.product_id AND m1.month >= m2.month
            GROUP BY m1.product_id, m1.month) AS x INNER JOIN
          mysales ON x.product_id = mysales.product_id AND x.month = mysales.month
```

This syntax for the update statement works on SqlServer, I don't know if it works also on MS Access.

Answer (score 2):

In `SqlServer`, you can project your column ranking directly using [`row_number()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
select 
    productid, 
    [month], 
    sales, 
    row_number() over (partition by productid order by [month]) - 1 as [Rank]
from mysales
```

Assuming the columns `[ProductId, MonthId]` constitute a key, you can persist this:

```
-- Create new column
ALTER TABLE mysales ADD [Rank] INT
GO

-- Set the new Column
UPDATE m 
    SET m.[Rank] = X.[Rank]
    FROM mysales m
    INNER JOIN
       (
         SELECT 
            ProductId, 
            Month, 
            row_number() over (partition by productid order by [month]) - 1 AS [Rank]
         FROM MySales
        ) X
    ON m.ProductId = X.ProductID AND m.[Month] = X.[Month];
```

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/569f8/1)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood it correctly, the months will always be sequential, right? Then just update the Counter column to (Month - 1).

```
UPDATE [table] SET [Counter] = [Month] - 1
```

Comment: No, I can't make this assumption. Some of products are not selling every month.

Comment: Oh, right... It ocurred to me right as I posted this answer... Sorry.